# What is the name and properties of this tree-like graph?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

What is the name and the properties of this tree-like graph?
What is the number of the paths (all going only down) from the first node (green) to any other node? For example, there are 7 paths from the green to the red node on the picture.

[image]

Comment: [OEIS A027907](https://oeis.org/A027907) gives path counts if always going down.

Comment: Thanks! The trinomial triangle is the answer to my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the answer was that it's the [trinomial triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrinomialTriangle.html).